# Get the IP address related to a RecentChange entry

Tags: mediawiki

I have an extension that needs to access the IP addresses associated with a recent change entry.

From the revision ID, I can access the [`Revision`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/Revision.html) object and in turn the associated [`RecentChange`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classRecentChange.html) but neither have any obvious methods to get the originating IP. It can only get the IP if it was an anonymous edit.

I have set `$wgPutIPinRC` so the IPs will be in the `recentchanges` table.

How can I get the IP address for the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not directly exposed as a property, but it is stored in the class as an attribute.
These can be read using the [`RecentChange::getAttribute()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classRecentChange.html#a75fd084ab866e977b47daf14f5dbe7bd) method passing the field name of `rc_ip`:

```
$ip_address = $this->recentchange->getAttribute( 'rc_ip' );
```

This still requires `$wgPutIPinRC` to be set for the data to be recorded in the first place.